# Approach to generate unique short number for current day

Tags: vb.net, random, logic, unique

I need to generate a number that is unique for the current day, I'm bound to use short data type and I tought to use hour/minute to achieve that.
This is my VB code:

```
Dim ora As String = dataora.Substring(6, 2) 'es. 07
Dim minuti As String = dataora.Substring(8, 2) 'es 14
Dim parteOra = ora * 1000
Dim parteMinuti = rando.Next(0, 708)
Dim parteFinale = rando.Next(0, 9000)
Dim CUL as short = CShort(parteOra + (minuti + parteMinuti) + parteFinale)
```

Knowing that short data type manage a 0-32767 range (from 0 up, I can't use negative) my question is: with the code above can I be 100% sure that in the same day I will always have an unique number?

My logic is:

- hour in 24h format is unique 0-23 number
- minutes is unique 0-59 number in the same hour
- parteOra can go from 0 to 23000
- minuti + parteMinuti can go from 0 to 767
- parteFinale can go from 0 to 9000
- putting all togheter I should have a range from 0 to 32767

Comment: What is `dataora`? Why you use string methods to resolve the minute and hour? The `DateTime` object has properties for that.

Comment: Also, what means _unique_ at all? If you execute this method 100000 times you want to get 100000 different values? Of course you can't get an infinite number of unique values of a data-type short.

Comment: Do you plan to generate one number only in a day? Or multiple numbers per one day? If multiple numbers per one day, how many in one day?

Comment: @TomHerman I forgot to specify that is related to employee marking their presence with badge on badge reader. So, it's not an infinite amount of executions, usually 2-3 people can mark their presence whitin the same minute of the same hour of the same day (but let's say 10 people in worst case scenario). I need to generate an unique number each time someone mark its presence.

Comment: @GabrieleCozzolino Do you need to be able to get the time back from the number? You could use (minutes since midnight) * 20 + (a sequential number from 0-19 for each event within the minute).

Comment: @AndrewMorton no I don't

Comment: @GabrieleCozzolino In that case, I suggest that you start at 0 and add 1 to get the next number. There doesn't appear to be any need to make it more complicated than that.

Comment: @GabrieleCozzolino - As I understand, you want to generate unique values within the same day only (meaning you can have the same value today and tomorrow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use `signed small int` as your data type, and can only use non negative values (values in the range of `0-32,767`) - as [Andrew Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115360/andrew-morton) suggested, you can create unique values per 1 day by multiplying the current minute since midnight by `20` and then add an increasing counter from `0` to `19`. The counter's value resets to `0` at the beginning of every minute, every minute.
The max value would be for the 19th employee checking in at 11:59pm - `28,799` which is inside the desired range.
Note that if more than 20 employees check in within the same minute, this system would fail.

Example:
For employees checking in at 4:37pm - the possible values within that minute would be `19,940-19,959` (4:37pm = `997` minutes since midnight, multiply by 20: `997*20=19,940`.

If you are able to use `unsigned small int` as your data type (this type uses 2 bytes per value, just like the `signed small int` data type), then the values can range from `0-65,535`. In this case, you can even allow 45 employees to check in within the same minute: multiply the current minute since midnight by `45` and then add an increasing counter from `0` to `44`. The counter's value resets to `0` at the beginning of every minute, every minute.

Example:
For employees checking in at 11:03pm - possible values within that minute would be `62,235-62,279`.